# How do I translate this string - PHP syntax question

Tags: php, theme-development, translation, localization

I need some help on how to correctly format this code snippet for translation:

```
<?php next_post_link( '%link', __( '<span class="meta-nav">←</span> Nästa nyhet') ); ?>
```

I've used this method in my theme before:

```
_e( 'Nästa nyhet', 'mytheme');
```

But I don't know how to correctly type the _e translation method in my link output.
I want to translate "Nästa nyhet".

Anyone?

Comment: Remember, `_e()` will `echo` a translated string and `__()` will `return` a translated string.

Comment: Hmm, I'm sorry I don't get it. I'm a designer guy just dabbling with wordpress themes and some minimal PHP. What's the difference in regard to translating wordpress strings? I've been using _e() throughout my theme and it has worked great so far. When should I use what?

Comment: Use `_e()` when you want to echo the content to the screen. Use `__()` when you want to return the translated string within a function for later manipulation.

Comment: Sooo...If I wanted to translate the url slug of some taxonomy in my functions file, I would do that using __()? And for just a headline outputted on my page, _e() is correct?

Comment: Yes. Take a look at [the Codex article](http://codex.wordpress.org/i18n) for internationalization for more details ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't wrap the entire section in `__()`, just wrap the part you need to translate:

```
<?php next_post_link( '%link', '<span class="meta-nav">←</span> ' . __( 'Nästa nyhet', 'mytheme' ) ); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked! I'll keep your advice in mind :)